# GCP: Unable to connect to Datalab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to connect to the datalab using the following command:

```
datalab connect <datalab name> --no-user-checking
```

it gives the following error message:

```
Connecting to <datalab name>.
This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair. To manage these keys, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8081
Could not request local forwarding.
```

Could someone please help me resolve the issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is usually generated when another Datalab or external process is running in the background by using the port 8081. You can kill the existing process or reset the machine where the tunnel to Datalab is running on.

In case you are using **Cloud Shell**, you can reset it by clicking the "**Options**" button next to the "**Web Preview**" button and clicking on **Restart** option. Afterwards, try to connect again the the Datalab instance:

```
datalab connect <datalab name> --port 8081
```